# Message Queues: passing ref to cloud bucket file store?

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, message-queue

I’ve seen applications of message queues where a reference to a cloud based object/file bucket is provided in the message. For instance a scanned PDF for processing. Is this type of MQ application only used with a single consumer?

If multiple consumers were subscribed to the topic, how would the distributed system know when to delete the object bucket? Perhaps this is typically done with a cleanup activity days later?

Thanks!